# IAM policies related to default VPC creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-vpc

I was reading [Default VPC and Default Subnets - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/default-vpc.html) about default VPC creation by AWS. Under default VPC components, it states "Amazon creates the above VPC components on behalf of the customers. IAM policies do not apply to those actions because the customers do not perform those actions".

My question is, we need to create an IAM role for an AWS service to call another AWS service, e.g., EC2 invoking S3, but why does IAM policy not work when the AWS builds resources on our behalf?

Thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example of Amazon EC2 connecting to Amazon S3, it is actually *your program code* running on an Amazon EC2 instance that is making calls to Amazon S3. The API calls to S3 need to be authenticated and authorized via IAM credentials.

There are also situations where an **AWS service calls another AWS service** *on your behalf* using a service-linked role, such as when Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling launches new Amazon EC2 instances. This requires provision of a [Service-Linked Role for Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/autoscaling-service-linked-role.html), which gives one service permission to call another service.

In the case of **creating a Default VPC**, this is something that AWS does *before* an account is given to a customer. This way, customers can launch resources (eg an Amazon EC2 instance) without having to first create a VPC. It is part of the standard account setup.

It appears that AWS has also exposed the `CreateDefaultVpc()` command to recreate the Default VPC. The documentation is saying that permission to make this API call is sufficient for creating the resources, without requiring permissions for each underlying call that it probably generates. I guess it is using the permissions that would normally be associated with a service-linked role, except that there is no service-linked role for VPC actions. If you are concerned about people creating these resources (eg an Internet Gateway), you can deny permissions on users for being able to call `CreateDefaultVpc()`, which will prevent them from using the command.

Answer (score 1):

Think of our AWS account as the "root" and AWS essentially has a "super root" account that they can trigger the initial creation of your account with. This all occurs when your account is initially set up and configured since they have that "super root" level of access just as part of being the product owners.

We are limited (and I assume AWS is limited in a different way) by IAM to allow us to use the [Principle of Least Privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege)